# null stack pointer exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I tried sending string from an activity to a fragment within a tab but i keep getting a null stack pointer exception.
This is the portion of code in the main activity that sends string to the fragment

```
//this portion of code  sends the user_name to the note fragment
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", name);
NoteFragment NF = new NoteFragment();
NF.setArguments(bundle);
```

This block of code receives the string in the fragment class.

```
//fragment class
public class NoteFragment extends Fragment{
    View v;
    String note, name, timestamp;
    EditText NOTE;
    noteOperations NO;
    Context ctx;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notelayout, container, false);
        ctx = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        NOTE = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.note);
        NO = new noteOperations(ctx);
        name = getArguments().getString("name");
        ImageButton save = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                note = NOTE.getText().toString();
                if (!note.equals(""))
                {
                    timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance     ().getTime());
                    NO.putInformation(NO,   note, timestamp, name);
                    NOTE.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat

```
10-04 06:52:48.848: D/Databsse operations(876): Database created
    10-04 06:52:50.151: D/Databsse operations(876): One row inserted
    10-04 06:52:51.207: D/gralloc_goldfish(876): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
    10-04 06:53:35.698: I/Choreographer(876): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    10-04 06:53:36.648: D/dalvikvm(876): GC_CONCURRENT freed 72K, 7% free 2716K/2908K, paused 15ms+175ms, total 1283ms
    10-04 06:53:38.288: I/Choreographer(876): Skipped 130 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    10-04 06:53:44.859: I/Choreographer(876): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    10-04 06:53:49.748: D/Databsse operations(876): Database created
    10-04 06:53:49.918: D/Databsse operations(876): Table combed
    10-04 06:53:50.291: I/Choreographer(876): Skipped 147 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    10-04 06:53:50.648: I/Choreographer(876): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    10-04 06:53:53.247: D/dalvikvm(876): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 208K, 11% free 2892K/3224K, paused 501ms, total 555ms
    10-04 06:53:53.378: I/dalvikvm-heap(876): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.545MB for 635812-byte allocation
    10-04 06:53:53.858: D/dalvikvm(876): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 9% free 3511K/3848K, paused 481ms, total 482ms
    10-04 06:53:54.938: D/AndroidRuntime(876): Shutting down VM
    10-04 06:53:54.958: W/dalvikvm(876): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
    10-04 06:53:55.128: D/dalvikvm(876): GC_CONCURRENT freed 33K, 9% free 3518K/3848K, paused 89ms+281ms, total 1265ms
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.databank/com.example.databank.Dashboard}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at com.example.databank.NoteFragment.<init>(NoteFragment.java:17)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at com.example.databank.Dashboard.onCreate(Dashboard.java:38)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    10-04 06:53:55.258: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  ... 11 more
    10-04 06:54:01.578: I/Process(876): Sending signal. PID: 876 SIG: 9
    10-04 06:54:04.928: D/Databsse operations(900): Database created
    10-04 06:54:06.328: D/Databsse operations(900): One row inserted
    10-04 06:54:07.408: I/Choreographer(900): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    10-04 06:54:07.498: D/gralloc_goldfish(900): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: Edit your answer to include a copy and paste of the complete stacktrace of the exception from logcat.

Comment: Ave added the logcat

Comment: What is line 17 in NoteFragment?

Comment: Looks the error is in the constructor for NoteFragment. You haven't shown that code.

Comment: Line 17: EditText NOTE;

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace clearly indicates that your NullPointerException is at line 17 in NoteFragment.java

You don't include line numbers, but the 16th and 17th lines of your example are:

```
ImageButton save = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

so I'm guessing that your variable 'save' is null because `v.findViewById(R.id.saveButton)` didn't find anything.

Oh, and it's a NullPointerException, not a "null stackpointer exception" this has nothing to do with the stack.

Comment: The 17th line is EditText NOTE;

Answer (score 0):

In the fragment class, I initialized a new bundle. This is the modification

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String name = bundle.getString("name");
```

This corrected the null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize the Bundle and it corrects the null pointer exception, that means getArguments() was returning null. It also means you haven't fixed the problem. Now the String name is null.

Make sure when you add the fragment, that you're adding the instance you called setArguments() on and not creating a new one.

Modify your code like this to handle the exception:

```
Bundle b;
if ((b = getArguments()) != null) {
    name = b.getString("name");
} else {
    name = "";
    Log.v(TAG, "No arguments set for NoteFragment")
}
```